# Adding rectangle in the background

Tags: lua, coronasdk

am new to lua and corona development and was following this tutorial from a book i just purchased, it teaches you how to add 3 white rectangles in the background to act as a background for some text we add later, when i type the code the boxes just stack to the left side and do not appear as they should be, am using **Corona SDK Version 2013.2100 (2013.12.7)** here is the code am using

```
-- adding rectangle in the background
rect_upperBackground = display.newRect( 0, 0, 320, 175 )
rect_upperBackground:setFillColor( 49,49,49 )
rect_upperBackground:toBack( )

rect_middleBackground = display.newRect( 0, 175, 320, 2 )
rect_middleBackground:setFillColor( 0,0,0 )
rect_middleBackground:toBack( )

rect_background = display.newRect( 0, 0, 320, 480 )
rect_background:toBack( )
```

Here is a picture of how it looks like on my end

[image: snapshot from simulator]

Comment: One of those boxes is black. What is your expected output?

Comment: to be full width of the screen 320

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted the person who wrote the tutorial and he said it wasn't written for Graphics 2.0 Corona has released. So i did some search on corona docs and found that if you add

```
graphicsCompatibility = 1
```

to the **config.lua** file in the content table, the existing code should work fine.

For information on this compatibility mode check http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/migration_v1.html

hope it helps anyone new who faced the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Look like your trying to use Scrollview to me.  Check out this documentation:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newScrollView.html

If you are just trying to create rectangles, check out this URL:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newRect.html

To manipulate the position of rectangles, you can use translate the x and y coordinates like this:

```
rect_upperBackground.x = display.contentWidth/2
rect_upperBackground.y = display.contentHeight/2
```

To manipulate the scale of rectangles, you can do this:

```
rect_upperBackground.xScale = 1.5
rect_upperBackground.yScale = 1.5
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) you see in the newRect link you posted it says display.newRect( x, y, width, height ) and that's what am doing i filled in the width and the height of the rectangle but it shows half screen instead of full screen, my screen size is set to 320 in config.lua . it still doesn't work

Comment: ok i think i found a solution but not sure if its the right way to do it i set .anchorX = 0 and .anchorY = 0 then then it worked as it should